# What do "reckless" and "deed" here means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I really have no clue about these two words meaning, even though i looked up the dictionary.

“Obama always goes **reckless** in words and **deeds** like a monkey in a tropical forest,” an unidentified spokesman at the commission’s Policy Department said in a statement carried by the official Korean Central News Agency.

Answer (score 1):

The spokesman is probably not a native speaker of English so maybe we should not read too much into it and just read it as "textbook English".

*Deeds* refers to actions done, *words* refers to words said.

According to him, what Obama says and does (i.e. using strong words against the DPRK without solid proof they were behind the hack) is reckless, which means it's done without considerations for consequences and acting on instincts (like a monkey, an animal not randomly chosen of course). 
The unstated consequences are the usual military threat which is implied every time they protest about something.